# Use a text file as storage for a very simple web application, how to do locking?

Tags: c#, locking, filestream, .net-3.0

I have a very simple web application that have to read and write in a text file. Basically, for each request the app looks for a specific line, if the line doesn't exists... it creates it. Not to mention that that operation has to be done in atomic fashion.

What is the best way to lock the file so only one http request can use at the time? And if possible, a way that doesn't throw exceptions when the file is locked :P

Define a `static readonly Object` in the page code and use it for do `lock()` ?
Using `System.IO.FileStream.Synchronized()` ?
Any other?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`FileStream.Lock()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: That way throws an IOException if the file is locked.